# Error al Insertar Datos EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

disculpen si la pregunta es muy obvia pero soy nuevo en el tema y buscando en google no encuentro nada sobre lo que sucede.

Tengo la Siguiente entidad.

```
public class Equipo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Serial { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public int IdTipoEquipo { get; set; }
        public int IdMarca { get; set; }
        public int IdRango { get; set; }
        public int IdResponsable { get; set; }
        public decimal PeriodoCalibracion { get; set; }
        public decimal Clase { get; set; }
        public string Patron { get; set; }
        public string ActivoFijo { get; set; }
        public string IdArticulo { get; set; }
        public int IdEstado { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioRegistro { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public string UsuarioActualiza { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaActualiza { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public List<EquipoDetalle> Detalle { get; set; }
    }
```

Como ven dentro de esa entidad va otra llamada detalle que es esta.

```
public class EquipoDetalle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("IdEquipo")]
        public int EquipoId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public int IdLaboratorio { get; set; }
        public string Certificado { get; set; }
        public string Observacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ProxVerificacion { get; set; }
        public int IdMovimiento { get; set; }
        // public byte[] Imagen { get; set; }
        public int? IdCalibracion { get; set; }
        public int IdResponsable { get; set; }
        public int IdEstado { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioRegistro { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public string UsuarioActualiza { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaActualiza { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public Programacion Programacion { get; set; }
    }
```

Y el detalle lleva dentro otra llamada programación que es esta.

```
public class Programacion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string IdEmpleado { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public int IdEquipoDetalle { get; set; }
        public int IdEstado { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioRegistro { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioActualiza { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaActualiza { get; set; }
    }
```

Con esa es donde tengo el problema, ya que el insert que quiero hacer es solo de Equipo y detalle mas no programación, programación va null pero en el momento en que hago el savechanges() me da un error y es porque programación va null, no se como decirle a entity que solo me haga el insert de las entidades que quiero y no de la ultima.

Agradezco su guia ya que estoy muy nuevo con entityFramework y tampoco se como buscar.

Este es el metodo de insert.

```
public int Add(Equipo item)
        {
            // Detalle
            item.Detalle = new List<EquipoDetalle>{
                    new EquipoDetalle{
                        Fecha= item.FechaRegistro,
                        IdLaboratorio = 1,
                        Observacion= "Registro de Equipo",
                        IdMovimiento = 1,
                        IdResponsable = item.IdResponsable,
                        IdEstado = item.IdEstado,
                        UsuarioRegistro= item.UsuarioRegistro,
                        UsuarioActualiza=item.UsuarioActualiza,
                        FechaRegistro=item.FechaRegistro,
                        FechaActualiza = item.FechaActualiza
                }
                    };
            try
            {
                _context.Equipo.Add(item);
                return _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 1;
            }

        }
```

Como ven viene lleno item y el detalle lo instancio, si comentareo la propiedad programación ya no me da error ya que no intenta hacer el insert.

Esta es la relacion.

[image: Relacion programacion - equipodetalle]

Comment: Cual es la relación con programación? por que no tienes el campo IdProgramacion, podrías poner el error que te sale?

Comment: Hola @maryrios justo ese es el error que me sale, que no existe ese campo aunq el lío es que no quiero hacer ese insert, empezando porque en la entidad programación tengo un campo idequipodetalle pero veo que el lo toma al revés buscando el campo idprogramacion en la entidad equipo detalle, que tendré mal?

Comment: podrías poner la clase programación? cual es la relacion con equipo detalle? 1..N, N..N o N..1?

Comment: Hola @maryrios muchas gracias por responder, acabo de agregar la clase programacion, se me habia pasado esa.
La relacion es 1 a 1, ya que por cada programacion que hago inserto un equipodetalle

Comment: creo que deberias remover `public Programacion Programacion { get; set; }` de `equipoDetalle` y a `Programacion` agregar `public EquipoDetalle EquipoDetalle{ get; set; },` ya que no estas haciendo bien la relación, si la relacion es de uno a uno, una de las clases debe de tener el nombre de la otra clase con la llave foranea que seria claseId

Comment: Hola @maryrios ummm pues no me lo he planteado asi, pero me nace una duda.
En la entidad Programacion tenemos un Campo que es "IdEquipoDetalle", al tener como foranea "IdEquipoDetalle" no hace que EquipoDetalle sea la principal??

Comment: no, así estas declarando un campo como cualquier otro sin relación a EquipoDetalle, mientras no agregues la clase no tiene como hacer el mapeo

Comment: ummm no entendi muy bien lo de "mientras no agregues la clase no tiene como hacer el mapeo", en la db tengo el join de ese campo con el id de equipodetalle.
Igual hare el cambio que me indicas y te cuento haber como me va

Comment: @maryrios tengo una duda, pero entonces la relacion debo hacerla al revez?? osea ahora en la entidad pongo a programacion como padre y a equipodetalle como hijo??? porque hay un proceso en el que debo insertar en programacion y en equipodetalle, asi que en esa parte quedo perdido ya que quitando esa relacion no se me darian las cosas. Ya que primero inserto en equipodetalle y luego ese id lo inserto en programacion en la columna idequipodetalle, por eso lo tenia como hijo. Que recomiendas?

Comment: es un poco confuso sin ver las relaciones correctamente, te recomiendo que cheques este [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), pero leyendo tus comentarios los atributos que debe tener cada clase serían (Equipo1-N EquipoDetalle, EquipoDetalle1-1Programacion): Equipo->List<EquipoDetalle> , EquipoDetalle->Equipo,EquipoId,Progracion y Programación-> EquipoDetalleId, EquipoDetalle. Espero quede mas claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que cheques este [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) 
cuando haces una relacion de uno a muchos tienes que en la tabla padre poner la lista de la clase hijo y en el hijo poner como atributo la clase padre y el id padre (Foreign key), si es de uno a uno en la clase padre pones el nombre de la otra clase y en la clase hijo el nombre de la clase padre y el Id(Foreign key).

Al no poner la propiedad [Required], no deberías tener problema al insertar un EquipoDetalle si no tienes Programación

```
class Equipo{
  ...
public virtual ICollection<EquipoDetalle> EquipoDetalles {get;set;}
}

class EquipoDetalle{
...
public virtual Equipo Equipo {get;set;}
public int EquipoId {get;set;}

public virutal Programacion Programacion {get;set;}
}

class Programacion{
...
   public int EquipoDetalleId {get;set;}
   public virtual EquipoDetalle {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, justo no tengo la propiedad [Required] pero aun asi me trata de insertar la programacion, la relacion en uno a uno, estoy tratando de buscar como subir aqui una imagen con el ejemplo de la relacion pero no veo como.

Comment: agregala a la pregunta principal (OP) :)

Comment: Jejeje si justo eso acabo de hacer, la ultima imagen es la relacion programacion - equipodetalle. Debi haber agregado tambien la de equipo?

Comment: intentaste insertar primero equipo y despues individualmente  equipoDetalle? En general si deberías poder hacer Equipo.Add(x) y guardar, pero si la relación no esta bien creada probablemente por eso da error [guardar lista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438574/adding-list-of-objects-to-context-in-ef)

Comment: No, es que son dos procesos, En el primero debo registrar un Equipo, Entonces en una sola transaccion Inserto el Equipo y su detalle (EquipoDetalle). Luego en otra ventana (otro proceso) voy a programar el equipo, entonces inserto el equipodetalle y luego la programacion, lo hago en ese orden ya que en programacion va el id del equipodetalle, el lio me lo pone entityFramework, hacia el proceso en ado.net sin problema :(